# Over which interval does f(x) have a negative average rate of change?

Tags: functions

I'm an adult learner of maths (self-studying). I've been struggling with this question and would like some help. I've been given 4 different x,y coordinates (indicated as stars on the image below) and have been asked to identify which out of those 4 coordinates signifies a negative average rate of change. Something very easy for most of you I'm sure. It doesn't make sense to me how a set of x,y coordinates constitute an interval? Any help, links to learning resources would be much appreciated.

Which set of x,y coordinates is correct and why?

[image: Image of Function with x,y coordinates]

Comment: Was the problem given as the picture, or as text? I can't make sense of the picture...

Comment: The problem was given as multiple choice. 4 coordinate choices were given which I've highlighted as stars on the chart. (-9,-8) - (-9,-3) - (3,8) - (3,5). One of those coordinates is supposed to be the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The four choices, $(-9,-8), (-9,-3)$ and so on, are not $(x,y)$ coordinates, but open intervals $(x_1,x_2)$ on the $x$-axis. Perhaps you are used to the notation $]x_1,x_2[$ for an open interval, but it means the same thing.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. If that's the case then the answer is [3,8] correct?

Comment: Yes :) Though you should take care in general to distinguish between open and closed intervals. What you just wrote, $[3,8]$, is a closed interval. (Not that it matters in this case.)